# add input values from arg in c into array for Sudoku solver

Tags: c, sudoku

I'm new to C and programming as a whole. I've got the basics down for a program I'm trying to get a better grasp of C, but I'm having trouble taking input from the users args at the command line to populate my array:

```
./sudoku.c "9...7...." "2...9..53" etc etc
```

I've tested my program using an array that I filled in and it works but that is no good if I can't take user input. My input looks something like this:

```
grid[9][9] = {{9, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0},
              {2, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 5, 3}};
```

Any suggestions?

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Please post the code you're actually using.

Answer (score 1):

Just read with simple loops.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int grid[9][9];
    int input_error = 0;
    int i, j;
    if (argc != 1 + 9) { /* check number of rows in input */
        input_error = 1;
    } else {
        for (i = 0; i < 9; i++) { /* read each rows */
            if (strlen(argv[i + 1]) != 9) { /* check number of cols in input */
                input_error = 1;
                break;
            }
            for (j = 0; j < 9; j++) { /* read each cols */
                if (isdigit(argv[i + 1][j]) && argv[i + 1][j] != '0') {
                    /* digits except for 0 */
                    grid[i][j] = argv[i + 1][j] - '0'; /* convert digit to integer */
                } else if (argv[i + 1][j] == '.') {
                    /* dot */
                    grid[i][j] = 0;
                } else {
                    /* invalid character */
                    input_error = 1;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    /* check if some errors are detected */
    if (input_error) {
        fputs("invalid usage\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }

    /* print what is read for testing */
    for (i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        for(j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
            printf(" %d", grid[i][j]);
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using text file as an input, and give filename as command line argument.

Example:

```html
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int lineCnt;
    int posCnt;
    FILE* inpFile = NULL;
 // check argument and file
 if( argc < 2 )
 {
  printf("run program with argument - name of file\n");
  return 1;
 }
 inpFile = fopen(argv[1], "r");
 if( inpFile == NULL )
 {
  printf("file %s cannot be open\n", argv[1]);
  return 2;
 }
 // reading from file
 int grid[9][9] = {0};
 int chr;
 for( lineCnt = 0; lineCnt < 9; lineCnt++)
 {
  for ( posCnt = 0; posCnt < 9; posCnt++)
  {
   // read next not sapce character from file
   do{
    chr = getc(inpFile);
   } while( isspace(chr) );
   // check character
   if( chr == EOF ) // file is finished but array is not filled
   { 
    printf("file %s if incomplete\n", argv[1]);
    return 3;
   }
   if(chr == '.') // if(chr == '.' || chr == '0')
   {
    grid[lineCnt][posCnt] = 0;
   }
   else if(chr > '0' && chr <= '9')
   {
    grid[lineCnt][posCnt] = chr - '0';
   }
   else
   {
    printf("file %s has incorrect format\n", argv[1]);
    return 4;
   }
  }
 }

 // test output of input data
 for( lineCnt = 0; lineCnt < 9; lineCnt++)
 {
  for ( posCnt = 0; posCnt < 9; posCnt++)
  {
   printf("%i ", grid[lineCnt][posCnt]);
  }
  printf("\n");
 }
}
```

If you compine this example and run as

```
./sudoku.c sudoku1.txt
```

where `sudoku1.txt` is like

```
1...5.7..
...3.5.91
.5.6.7.87
11111....
....2222.
6.6.6.6.6
.1.1.1.1.
1.1.1.1.1
.9.9.9.99
```

you will understand my idea